# What is the meaning of command `:4w`?

Tags: vimrc, buffers

As title. I just read a post that people accidentally **delete**(wipeout) their unsaved work by trying the command `:4w`. A bloody lesson to him, but I also want to prevent this from happening to myself. Might sound ridiculous but I use `:w` quite often, as maybe I would have a chance to mis-type a number between `:` and `w`.

Could anyone point me to the documentation, as I don't know how to search it in this case since there is a pretending `4`. (I tried `:h :w` but nothing seems to related to wiping things out. Maybe the poster remap `w` to something else? I don't know)

I would also like to know how to remap all `:[N]w` to `<nop>` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It writes line 4 to the file.

Her is what the doc is saying (`help :w`):

```
:[range]w[rite][!] [++opt]
    Write the specified lines to the current file.  This
    is unusual, because the file will not contain all
    lines in the buffer.
```

The following code correct the `write` command to remove the simple range

```
function! CorrectWriteCommand()
  if getcmdtype() != ':'
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  if matchstr(getcmdline(), '^\(\d\+\(:\d*\)\?\)\?w\%[rite]!\?\>') == ''
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  " Parse the cmd line
  let l:cmdline = getcmdline()
  let l:newcmdline = l:cmdline
  let l:good = v:true

  if matchstr(l:cmdline, '^\d\+\(:\d*\)\?') != ''
    echo 'match'
    let l:newcmdline = substitute(l:cmdline, '^\d\+\(:\d*\)\?', '', 'g')
    let l:good = v:false
  endif

  if l:good
    return "\<CR>"
  else
    return "\<C-u>" . l:newcmdline
  endif

endfunction
cnoremap <expr> <CR> CorrectWriteCommand()
```

Comment: So the command `:[range]w` is kinda like the concept of git-hunk-stage in that it only stages selected lines(hunks) to git?

Comment: The range save truck the file where the git hunk only stage some lines. I suppose it only make sense when you want to save an excerpt of the file.

Comment: That means I misunderstood it. Thanks for your correction. So running `:[N]w` does be able to wipe-out/discard some existing lines of the current buffer, right?

Comment: :4w foo.txt save into foo.txt the 4th and only the 4th line of the buffer foo.txt will contain only one line. :4:6w foo.txt will save into foo.txt the lines between 4 and 6, foo.txt will contains 3 lines :-)

Comment: and Vim will say something like: "vim the file has been changed since reading it" after the writing, right? (my new question aside, thanks a lot for your example!)